# why does next auth say that client_id is required, even though in discord providers, there clearly is a client_id

Tags: oauth, discord, next.js, next-auth

When I try to use next auth to create a discord oauth client and I click sign in, I get this error:

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#get_authorization_url_error client_id is required {
  message: 'client_id is required',
  stack: 'TypeError: client_id is required\n' +
    '    at new BaseClient (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:178:13)\n' +
    '    at new Client (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1823:7)\n' +
    '    at openidClient (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client.js:28:18)\n' +
    '    at getAuthorizationUrl (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/authorization-url.js:67:51)\n' +
    '    at Object.signin (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:37:60)\n' +
    '    at NextAuthHandler (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:191:39)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuthNextHandler (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:21:19)\n' +
    '    at async /Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:57:32\n' +
    '    at async Object.apiResolver (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils.js:101:9)',
  name: 'TypeError'
}
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error client_id is required {
  error: {
    message: 'client_id is required',
    stack: 'TypeError: client_id is required\n' +
      '    at new BaseClient (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:178:13)\n' +
      '    at new Client (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1823:7)\n' +
      '    at openidClient (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client.js:28:18)\n' +
      '    at getAuthorizationUrl (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/authorization-url.js:67:51)\n' +
      '    at Object.signin (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:37:60)\n' +
      '    at NextAuthHandler (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:191:39)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuthNextHandler (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:21:19)\n' +
      '    at async /Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:57:32\n' +
      '    at async Object.apiResolver (/Users/muyuan/Documents/minibot/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils.js:101:9)',
    name: 'TypeError'
  },
  provider: {
    id: 'discord',
    name: 'Discord',
    type: 'oauth',
    authorization: {
      url: 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize',
      params: [Object]
    },
    token: { url: 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', params: {} },
    userinfo: { url: 'https://discord.com/api/users/@me', params: {} },
    profile: [Function: profile],
    idToken: false,
    checks: [ 'state' ],
    client_id: my client id(not actually 'my client id'),
    client_secret: my client secret(not actually 'my client secret'),
    signinUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/discord',
    callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/discord'
  },
  message: 'client_id is required'
}
```

This is how I defined my discord provider:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord"

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
        client_id: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ],
  secret: "hello1234567890",
  debug: true
})
```

There is clearly a client_id. Why is it still giving me that error?
Also on my website when I click "Log in with discord", it says "try signing in with a different account".

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but have you tried changing the config object properties names?

I believe they should be `camelCase` rather than `snake_case`


✅    "clientId"

❌    "client_id"

```
DiscordProvider({
    clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error yesterday, and it was be because my .env file had mi variables defined in this style:

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=akakasjakandiaak
```

I change the definition to this style and the error is gone.

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID="akakasjakandiaak"
```

*Dotenv documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv*

Comment: thanks, i already fixed this error many months ago lol

Answer (score 1):

**Error**:  Its really simple actually, your client ID is missing (i mean the real string id not the variable pointing to it i.e in your case "DISCORD_CLIENT_ID")

**Solution**: Create a .env file and put the real client id(from firebase) string in it, its is most probably missing , this is if you are testing your application locally, if hosting on vercel or netifly set this string on the environment variables.

i.e your .env.local file should look like:

```
  1 # Authentication                                                                                                                                                    
  2 DISCORD_CLIENT_ID = 
  3 DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET =
  4 NEXTAUTH_URL = http://localhost:3000
  5 
  6 FACEBOOK_ID =
  7 FACEBOOK_SECRET =
  8
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I had it in `.env`, but not in `.env.local`, so I guess it was overwriting it with an empty string during local development.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old. But probably the problem is that the function is getting called in the client side, and there is no 'process.env' in client side.

Answer (score 0):

2hours+ later I found out that I was using ":" instead of "="

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID:ghsttsy.......
instead of

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=ghsttsy.......

Answer (score -1):

i was facing same issue but i found a solution youtube after 2 days

**Solution :**
[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vFLgrPpVY&t=13s)

**OR**

change your linkedin Provider with

```
 LinkedInProvider({
        clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
        token: {
            url: "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
            async request({
                              client,
                              params,
                              checks,
                              provider
                          }) {
                const response = await client.oauthCallback(provider.callbackUrl, params, checks, {
                    exchangeBody: {
                        client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
                        client_secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    }
                });
                return {
                    tokens: response
                };
            }
        },
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your location of .env.local is incorrect. It should be in the root.

Answer (score -1):

Check for the location of your .env file.  I put console log in various places to see if I am logging out env variables.  Turns out my .env file was in the wrong directory (I did not have it in my root folder).

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment instead

Comment: Until you get the privilege to comment please add some sources for your answer when posting.